# Restful commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I am new to RESTful stuff.  But, I want to use it in my rails app.  When I add this to my routes.rb `map.resources :notes` I get routes to these methods created:

- index
- create
- new
- edit
- show
- update
- destroy

What I am wondering is what is the difference between edit/update and create/new?  Is there any standard definitions of how these method pairs vary and what each one does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the scaffold generator in Rails 2 `create` is the action called when the form from the `new` action is submitted.  Likewise, `update` is the action called when the form from the `edit` action is submitted.

As far as I know, you can blow that away and define them to do whatever you want depending on what `create/new/edit/update` means to your application.

Answer (score 13):

The standard definition is as follows:

- **index** - GET - A view of all (or a selection of) the records
- **show** - GET - A view of a single record
- **new** - GET - A form to post to create
- **create** - POST - Create a new record
- **edit** - GET - A form to edit a single record
- **update** - PUT - Update a record
- **destroy** - DELETE - Delete a record